# while comparing content of sms with text it's not working. can any one please help me to solve

Tags: android

While comparing the content of sms with text, it's not working. Can any one please help me solve this? Here I want the count of a and b based on sms content. If sms content is a, it will give count 1. If another sms also has content a, then count must be incremented to 1 i.e., 2. Below is my code:

```
    package com.example.sms;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Sms extends Activity {
    int count=0;
    int count1=0;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms);
          TextView view1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
          TextView view2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
          Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
          Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,null);
          String sms = "";
          String data = null;
          while (cur.moveToNext()) {
              sms =cur.getString(12);

                  if(sms=="a"){
                      count=count+1;
                      view1.setText("a"+count+")");
                  }

                  else if(sms=="b"){
                      count1=count1+1;
                      view2.setText("a("+count+")");
                  }
                  else{
                      //view1.setText("no data");
                  }
              //data.add(cur.getString(12));
             // view1.setText(cur.getString(12));
          }

          //view1.setText(sms);
          //setContentView(view);
      }
    }
```

Comment: yes. its working thank you jonhopkins.

Comment: @user2949416 please accept an answer below when time permits since it fixed your problem. Also, see my note on an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `String` class in Java is not a primitive type. Because of this, the `==` operator will not give you the results you expect- it will compare memory addresses, not the contents of the Strings.

You should use the `equals()` method of the String class to compare strings.

In this case, you would use:

```
if (sms.equals("a") {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Just a side note: Using `if ("a".equals(sms))` will protect against `NPE` because `"a"` will never be `null` but `sms` could be.

Comment: @codeMagic that's a great idea. I never thought to do that before.

Answer (score 3):

Your comparison isn't working because you need to use `.equals()` to compare strings.

```
if (sms.equals("a")){
    count = count + 1;
    view1.setText("a" + count + ")");
}
else if (sms.equals("b")){
    count1 = count1 + 1;
    view2.setText("a(" + count + ")");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use `.equals()` instead of `==` for strings